# APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING not working anymore for version 3.5.0 and 3.5.1

Tags: azure-application-insights

is APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING  not working anymore for version 3.5.0 and 3.5.1 ?
because i downgrade version 3.4.19 there are some logs in monitoring azure .

Comment: It would be a good idea to indicate what language you are using, and how the connection string is defined. I suspect that this is Java based on the version mentioned. APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING should work if defined as ENV variable.

Comment: What is the version and framework of your App? How you have configured ApplicationInsights?Can you explain the issue with more details.

Comment: hi Julien   i use java language. when you use APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING  in env .application insight. configuration is automatic no need implementation.

Comment: i use only java and dropwizard java 17

Comment: "connectionStringConfiguredAtRuntime": true,"connectionString": "${APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING}",

Comment: i resolved to delete connectionString in  my application.json because i have log error connection string failed try ${file:myfile} . it worked now tx guy

Comment: @MarcelPagnol - Please post your sol as an answer.